# Order of features in chemical descriptors

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

ECFP are small-molecule descriptors, which are usually represented as a bit vector. I wonder if order of elements of this vector matters, in other words, if this vector encodes any positional information. I couldn't find this information in the papers.

Thank you

Comment: This article suggests they are arranged in a particular way to prevent order dependence: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ci100050t "...(the neighbors
are ordered using their identifiers, and the order of the
attaching bonds, to avoid order-dependence)"

Comment: thanks, but I am still confused, is there positional information or not? will I get another compound if I randomly shuffle the bits in the vector?